# modify bash ls command to sort by ending characters

Tags: python, bash, sorting, ls, listdir

I have a directory with a lot of log files like `sample_step1[_step2[_step3]].log`

to check complition of each step I run `python ls_end.py`, which is

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import getsize, isfile

def end_sort(s): return s[::-1]


files = [i for i in listdir('.') if isfile(i) and not i.startswith('.')]
for i in sorted(files, key=end_sort):
    print("{:10.2f}\t{}".format(getsize(i)/1024, i))
```

is there any alternative in bash to sort files in directory from the ending ?

Comment: You could sort by modification date. I assume that's what your naming scheme is based on?

Comment: unfortunately no, for each sample i run parallel pipeline processing, some of steps fail and i have to re run then, so `ls -t` cmd doesn't solve my problem correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a highly unorthodox sorting method, but you could do it easily enough in bash if you have the `util-linux` package installed, which includes the `rev` utility:

```
ls | rev | sort | rev
```

Another possibility, which is a slightly more conventional sort, would be:

```
ls | sort -t_ -k4 -k3,3 -k2,2
```

That will sort each `step` field in normal order, but will place files with missing `step2` and `step3` in a different order, which may or may not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
ls | rev | sort | rev
```

?